# Postfix + Gmail. Certificate verification failed

Tags: 11.10, gmail, postfix

I have setup my system to send emails via Gmail.

The system works in so far as I can send emails, however I'm getting an
error regarding the secure certificate.

This is an example entry in the mail.log:

```
    Oct 29 12:17:27 durban postfix/smtp[20742]: setting up TLS connection
    to smtp.gmail.com[209.85.143.108]:587

    Oct 29 12:17:27 durban postfix/smtp[20742]: certificate verification
    failed for smtp.gmail.com[209.85.143.108]:587: untrusted issuer
    /C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority

    Oct 29 12:17:27 durban postfix/smtp[20742]: Untrusted TLS connection
    established to smtp.gmail.com[209.85.143.108]:587: TLSv1 with cipher
    RC4-SHA (128/128 bits)

    Oct 29 12:17:29 durban postfix/smtp[20742]: BA4852A1BFA:
    to=<some@email.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[209.85.143.108]:587,
    delay=2.9, delays=0.1/0.1/1.3/1.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0
    OK 1319887049 l20sm20686943wbo.6)
```

I googled this issue and have found others with the problem who were
able to solve it by updating a file called cacert.pem in the
/etc/postfix directory.

In my main.cf I have the following line (amongst others):

```
smtpd_tls_CAfile=/etc/postfix/cacert.pem
```

I have this file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2298 2011-10-29 12:16 cacert.pem
```

I populated this file with the commands:

```
# cat /usr/lib/ssl/certs/Equifax_Secure_CA.pem >> /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
# cat /usr/lib/ssl/certs/Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem >>
      /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
```

I believe the first line should suffice and the second line
(certificate) is an old no longer used (by google) certificate.

I don't know what else I can change and don't have any idea on what else
to search for or which logfiles to check.

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue and when I issued "postconf |grep smtp|grep CA" all the variables were empty:
smtp_tls_CAfile = 
smtp_tls_CApath = 
smtpd_tls_CAfile = 
smtpd_tls_CApath =

Here's how I fixed it;

I assume your Ubuntu install created the CA path that contains all known CAs on the internet: /etc/ssl/certs, and Equifax is there.

All you're missing in your Postfix configuration is the **CApath**:
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs

Afterwards Postfix will be able to verify smtp.gmail.com's certificate as legit CA because it has it in the /etc/ssl/certs directory.

Comment: Quick and easy way to add this when you are in a hurry `sudo postconf -e 'smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs'` then `sudo service postfix restart`

Comment: The `CApath` setting is not useful if the smtp daemon runs in a chroot jail, which it usually does.

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is that you're setting `smtpd_tls_CAfile` instead of `smtp_tls_CAfile`.

You can use a self-signed certificate for your postfix TLS configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same configuration as you. But in addition to

```
smtpd_tls_CAfile=/etc/postfix/cacert.pem
```

I also have in my postfix's `main.cf`:

```
smtp_tls_CAfile=/etc/postfix/cacert.pem
```

Try adding this extra line. You might need to add it as part of this block:

```
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/FOO-cert.pem
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/FOO-key.pem
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtp_tls_session_cache
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which I fixed with the help of [this blogpost](http://stevejenkins.com/blog/2011/09/how-to-use-a-free-startssl-certificate-in-postfix-for-ssltls/).

The remedy seemed to be that I just needed a valid SSL certificate (not a self-signed one), and I concatenated the StartSSL and Equifax CA bundles together.